# How to Pass PassEventArgsToCommand along with CommandParameter in Interaction.Triggers

Tags: c#, wpf, command, mouseevent, eventtrigger

I need to Pass **PassEventArgsToCommand** along with **CommandParameter** in **Interaction.Triggers** - WPF C#

My XAML Source Code:

```
<i:Interaction.Triggers>
    <i:EventTrigger EventName="MouseDoubleClick">
        <commandHelper:EventToCommand PassEventArgsToCommand="True" Command="{Binding OpenDetailsCommandByLeftMouseBtn}" CommandParameter="Provider"/>
    </i:EventTrigger>
</i:Interaction.Triggers>
```

For me it throws an exception **Invalid cast from 'System.String' to 'System.Windows.Input.MouseButtonEventArgs'**.

Answer (score 0):

You can use InvokeCommandAction.

```
 <i:Interaction.Triggers>
                <i:EventTrigger EventName="MouseDoubleClick">
                    <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding ButtonClickCommand}" CommandParameter="parameter"/>
                </i:EventTrigger>
            </i:Interaction.Triggers>
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, it may pass the EventArgs ?

Comment: @B.Balamanigandan, yes by using `PassEventArgsToCommand = True`